# How can I use Regex to check if multiple strings appear at the start of a phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to check if a phone number has either of the following 031, 039, 076, 077, 078 at the start. I'm able to check if one of them occurs once
`(096){1}` but not able to check the input if any of them occur at least once.
How would I check if any of the sequences appear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an alternation here.  Assuming the phone numbers were all digits, and you had no other requirements, you could use:

```
^(?:031|039|076|077|078)\d+$
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. You also made me think of what other requirements I might need like limiting the total number.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can write the pattern with an alternation and character classes as:

```
^(?:03[19]|07[678])\d+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OkR9Vy/1)

Note that this will match starting from 4 digits.

If you want for example to match at least 10 digits, you can use a quantifier:

```
^(?:03[19]|07[678])\d{7,}$
```